# Android Sqlite table column foreign keys?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating a fairly simple sqlite db for my android project.  It has been a long time since i have written msql commands, let alone sqlite.

To keep this question simple, lets just say i have two tables.  One table for `dogs` and another for `owners`.

In `dogs` there will be a column to hold the owner's `_id` which will be a primary key from the other table.

I can't for the life of me remember how to do this in sqlite or if i even can.

I am creating the dog table with this String :

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DOGS = "CREATE TABLE"
            + TABLE_DOGS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_OWNER + " INTEGER );";
```

Comment: So, you need an INNER JOIN? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite does not have foreign keys enabled by default. You'll need to execute `pragma FOREIGN_KEYS=ON;` every time before using the database.

To create the actual foreign key relation, add a column to your dogs table like this: `FOREIGN KEY(owners_id) REFERENCES owners(_id)`. You should also define rules for constraint violations.

For more information on SQLite foreign keys, check out https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Hi Jschools, I am getting foreign key as nulls.Can you please look at it.These are my 2 tables Table 1 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists scannerValuess (id integer,partName text null,cost text null,foreign key(id) references scannerUserValuess(userid))"; Table 2 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table if not exists scannerUserValuess (userid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,mobile text not null,address text not null,date text not null)"; Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "getting foreign key as nulls", but I would guess that since your `scannerValuess` table references your `scannerUserValuess` table, you need to create `scannerUserValuess` first.